# ODBC Linked Server in SQL 2014 Express Server Data Truncated

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, odbc

I have been trying to collect data from ODBC Server into my SQL Server 2014 Express. I am successfully able to run the query:

```
select * from openquery(test,'SELECT * FROM Sample/hstrh3.current')
```

Result is as shown in image:

[image: SQL SERVER LINKED SERVER ERROR]

But as you can see, as marked in red, my Data is cut off / truncated.

```
Z522_AOS:CGC2H4AFDPP.P
```

whereas in original source it's

```
Z522_AOS:CGC2H4AFDPP.PNT
```

why data is being cut off / truncated?

Please suggest better way in which I can avoid such glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried querying the columns in a qualified manner instead of using SELECT *?  This would give you an opportunity to cast a particular value as a high(ish) limit NVARCHAR:

```
SELECT [Time]
,[Status]
,[Source]
,[Description]
,[Value]
FROM OPENQUERY([**RemoteServer**], 'SELECT [Time]
                       ,[Status]
                       ,CAST([Source] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Source]
                       ,[Description]
                       ,[Value]
                        FROM [RemoteDatabase].[schema].[RemoteTable]')
```

Also, the table you have open in the explorer is 'data', but you're searching for [current].  Why not fully qualify the table name you're querying from?

```
SELECT [Time]
,[Status]
,[Source]
,[Description]
,[Value]
FROM OPENQUERY([**RemoteServer**], 'SELECT [Time]
                   ,[Status]
                   ,CAST([Source] AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Source]
                   ,[Description]
                   ,[Value]
                    FROM [RemoteDatabase].[schema].[RemoteTable]')
```

Comment: Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
OLE DB Provider "MSDASQL" for linked Server "test" Memory Allocation Failure
OLE DB Provider "MSDASQL" for Linked Server "test" Table not found

I am getting above error while i am trying to execute above query given in Answer..

Comment: You need to ensure that you fill in the "blanks" and the table you are looking to query is correct.  I made my table qualifications based on what I saw in your screenshots.  Is your table in the remote server the [data] table in the [Sample/hstrh3] database?  I'll edit my response for ease of use.

Comment: Also, looking at this further, this seems more like it's an issue with the way the data is being populated into the Remote Table.  You'll need to make sure that the data in the source table is correct before you proceed further down the line.

Comment: select * from openquery(test,'SELECT * FROM Sample/hstrh3.current')

I use this query to call from remote server (ODBC). Data table i created was temporary to store data from remote server for further processing of data.

Issue i am facing while using select * from openquery(test,'SELECT * FROM Sample/hstrh3.current')

directly reading i am getting data truncated or sometimes i get error if i Query * upto 3 Colums. More than 3 Columns i get error Catastrophic failure.

I am really confused why is it happening ?

Comment: I would suggest making that "temporary" table a more permanent holding table.  This table would house the current data that needs to be processed further, and would be truncated at the start of each "run" of your process.  At least with a "permanent" holding table you can define your data types and make sure that you can rule out possible issues.  Furthermore: this ODBC connection: is it access? a flat file?

Comment: i am using ODBC Connection that provides data in Flat file format. I have more than 30000 Rows having column data of maximum char length of 32 maximum.  i have already used insert into permanent_database,then open query. But i am not successful in that too. Data Gets truncated.

Comment: I think you may need to confirm that your flat file is not the problem (or the process that imports it).  I think the problem lies somewhere other than Th OpenQuery you're doing, further back in the process.  Start by confirming that the data that's being truncated doesn't contain a delimiter or carriage return, and also confirm that you're not using a fixed width of some sort.  I'd also suggest using the SQL Server Import wizard or SSIS to import the data from your flat file.

Comment: It is not a FLAT File. I am taking data from History server which is giving data via ODBC and taking it into sql. then after process i want to convert it into flat file for further transfer. But i am getting data truncation issue when the data arrives in SQL. In ODBC Query tools and Excel data is perfect. But only in SQL Data gets truncated.